# slice() to the array of object didn't return a reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reference, slice

Please help me, I am really confused with the `slice()` of javascript. I have read the documentation of `Array.prototype.slice()`. It said :

> For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.

In this code, I use `slice()` to actual object but it still returns a reference

```
var arObj = [
    { 'name': 'Jon',  'age': 24 },
    { 'name': 'Mark', 'age': 32 },
    { 'name': 'Kacy', 'age': 22 }
];

// use splice to copy array of objects into second variable
var ar2 = arObj.slice();

// modify property value in copy
ar2[1].name = 'Bill';

// view original (also modified)
console.log( arObj[1].name ); // Bill
```

And the second code, it doesn't:

```
let data = this.state.data.slice(); //If you don't have the slice function, it will return a reference.
console.log(this.state.data);
data.reverse();
```

if I try to reverse or change value of data, the value of (this.state.data) won't change. This is the structure of this.state.data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/94emV.png

Comment: `.reverse()` does not mutate any of the items in the array, it only mutates the array itself (and if the array was just created with `slice`, nothing outside of the sliced array will be affected)

Comment: But the data is a reference of (this.state.data). If the data is reversed, the this.state.data must also be reversed, right ? And if I change the value of the object in the data array, the (this.state.data) doesn't change.

Comment: Nothing outside the sliced array will be affected ?. How about my first code ?. You can try it in your browser

Comment: Because you sliced it, it's not just a reference to the `this.state.data` array - you created a *new* array with `.slice`, so re-arranging the items in the *new* array any way won't change how they're ordered in the original array.

Comment: Your original code is mutating an *item* in the array. Your `this.state.data` code is mutating the *newly created array*, but not any individual items.

Comment: Exactly, just log both the old and the new array and you'll see they're not the same.

Comment: No, slice returns a new array that you then reversed.  If you mutate elements of the reversed array, **then** original elements in `this.state.data` will mutate.

Comment: Is it possible that `this.state` is being updated by another function, thereby making it entirely distinct from `data`?

Comment: Sorry, it is my stupid bug. Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/533kyorr7p illustrates

Comment: Thank you, that's my fault Drew Reese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me, and sorry for my stupid bug. The reverse() function won't affect the original array. It will be only affected if you mutate the value of one or more items in the reference array.